# update on a record where count(pessoas_i) == 2 and percentage is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Legal Persons and I need to update the percentages according to the number of occurrence of their id in the table. The ids can be repeated, so I have to group them count(id), to update the value of the percentage field according to the number of occurrences of the ids

I tried something like:

```
UPDATE `mydb`.`Legal_Persons` 
SET `percentual` = 100 
where id_pessoas in(
  SELECT id_pessoas, COUNT(id_pessoas) 
  FROM Legal_Persons 
  where percentual is null  
  GROUP BY id_pessoas 
  HAVING COUNT(id_pessoas) = 1
  order by id_pessoas
);
```

error:  1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: `SELECT id_pessoas, COUNT(id_pessoas) ` - you don't need to select `COUNT()` here, leave just `SELECT id_pessoas` and leave the rest of your query as is. Based on the title of your question, you might want to change 1 in `HAVING COUNT(id_pessoas) = 1`  to 2.

Comment: making the following change:

UPDATE `mydb`.`Legal_Persons` SET `percentual` = 100 where id_pessoas in
(
SELECT id_pessoas
FROM Legal_Persons
where percentual is null  
HAVING COUNT(id_pessoas) = 1 
order by id_pessoas);


a new error arose:

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'Legal_Persons' for update in FROM

Answer (score 0):

Do not use subquery in WHERE, use multiple-table UPDATE:

````sql
UPDATE Legal_Persons AS t1
JOIN ( SELECT id_pessoas
       FROM Legal_Persons 
       WHERE percentual IS NULL  
       GROUP BY id_pessoas 
       HAVING COUNT(id_pessoas) = 1
       ) AS t2 USING (id_pessoas)
SET percentual = 100;
```sql
````